# Why are there numbers in Gradle cache directories?

Tags: java, gradle

A downloaded dependency, e.g. `log4j` is cached in the [Gradle user home directory](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/directory_layout.html#dir:gradle_user_home) like `~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.apache.logging.log4j/log4j`.

But why `modules-2` and `files-2.1` instead of `modules` and `files`?

It doesn't look like the version of Gradle. For instance, there is no "6" or "6.0" while I'm using Gradle 6.0 on my PC.

```
~/.gradle/caches/jars-1
~/.gradle/caches/jars-2
~/.gradle/caches/jars-3
~/.gradle/caches/modules-2
~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1
~/.gradle/caches/transforms-1
~/.gradle/caches/transforms-2
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The numbers refer to different layouts needed by different versions of gradle. Whenever there is a breaking change in the cache layout in a new version of gradle these numbers will be incremented.

If a new version of gradle still uses the same cache layout as the previous one, these numbers don't get incremented. Thus the new version can use the already existing caches without wasting disk space.

For example the number of the modules, files and metadata directory changed with this commit for a layout change introduced with gradle 1.9

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/commit/aace47c2e5f8d137fadc6b07baf84371efb48c09